# Best Practice/Pattern to Populate 'ViewModel' objects

Tags: .net, design-patterns, mvvm

Folks,

I'm trying to figure out a pattern or best practice to translate data from the domain objects/data source over to the 'ViewModel' object. In my particular example, the domain object is the WCF proxy objects. Any call to the WCF methods will populate these proxy objects which finally gets transferred over to the 'ViewModel' objects. See [Architectural diagram](http://www.flickr.com/photos/8922855@N07/5531049962/sizes/z/in/photostream/)

This microsoft article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx talks about using a Repository pattern. It's mentioned under 'The Data Model and Repository' section. Is that the best approach? Can someone advice me?

dorman

Comment: I'm adding a class diagram so that we can drilldown. [Class Diagram](http://flic.kr/p/9tpBQN)                                              Do y'all agree with comment B: (see image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to have a repository. 
That will give you some advantages, like easy testing of the view model; also an easy switching to another kind of repository later.

In terms of the article you provided, - it gave them an advantage of unit-testing the view-model logic; and, later on, they can switch from XML files repository to the SQL server repository (as an example).

Just make sure to have abstract repository injected into ViewModel.

Comment: Tengiz...I think the repository pattern will only apply on the data source side. In my case, it would be the WCF layer where the data is retrieved and inserted. What do you think? See class diagram....can we apply the Repository pattern anywhere? Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: dormantroot: you should not manipulate the data which is returned by wcf in you domain (business) layer. Instead - look at a wcf layer as a data-access layer, from which the data comes. So at a bare minimum you should build a domain data objects which wrap wcf-returned objects (in fact, it's better to transform wcf objects to domain objects after retrieval). Thus you should work with your domain objects instead of wcf ones. Makes sense?

Comment: Tengiz: Yes you are right! I wouldn't use WCF object directly. I would definetly create an layer of domain objects. The class diagram I had was based on an example from a book. So it would be WCF Objects ---->Domain Objects----->ViewModel--->View. So, what pattern can we use so that WCF Objects and Domain Objects are loosely coupled?

Comment: dormantroot: that is exactly the repository pattern you need - just as in the article. Repository should manipulate domain objects, like finding, saving, etc. And a ViewModel needs to have an abstract repository injected in it and should call it when needed. And, when constructing the ViewModel in you app, you should pass one implementation of abstract repository. In your case that will be the implementation which uses wcf service as a data store. Clear?

Answer (score 2):

Repository pattern is related to data access layer (what is inside your WCF). This has nothing to do with presentation layer.

I would suggest you declare your Model and ViewModel classes in MVC project based on the requirements for the UI (without taking your database schema into consideration). You can then use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com) to simplify the code needed to copy values from WCF proxy classes to your Models. You might want to encapsulate this code in an Adapter class that will shield the rest of app from AutoMapper code.

EDIT:

Do not use your WCF proxies as model classes. Declare separate model classes based on your UI and use AutoMapper to copy data between them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. See attached class diagram (comment A:).....does the Adapter Pattern still apply?

Comment: Thanks Jakub... yes, you are correct! I wouldn't use WCF proxy objects. I was referring to an example that I found in a book. So, going back to your comment, if I understood it correctly, I would be doing something like this:   WCF<---->>AutoMapper<<----->Domain/Model Objects------>ViewModel -----> View  , correct? If so, we still run into the problem of coupling WCF objects with Domain/Model objects through AutoMapper. What do you think?

Comment: Also, what's your suggestion about comment B: (in the class diagram)?

Comment: There is no coupling thanks to the AutoMapper, it acts as an adapter in order to remove coupling. And yes, use DI.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, and have a single responsibility per class.

This suggests some separation between the objects returned by your proxy (Communication Objects) and the ones used by your ViewModel (View Objects). This way the client-side logic is decoupled from the communication/transmission method.

If you have WCF service closely related to UI elements, then simply translate from CO to VO. Since the view is bound to VOs, then view gets updated.

If you need to insert business or domain logic on the client, translate to an intermediary domain object. Then have the object interact with the other domain model objects (the so-called repository in the article you mention). VO should listen to domain changes and react accordingly. This pattern suggests the domain objects have no dependency on WCF nor WPF.